# Create a input table using property grid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I want to create an input table using `property grid` for an excel as displayed in image below where strings are properties and the values in blue are input. I don't know how to do it. Help will be extremely appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything or just want code?

Comment: I am a naive and learning to use C#. So I just need idea about adding property to it.

Comment: Thanks, to everyone concern, I have solved my problem.